# How can I polish black shoes without getting polish on my white soles?

Tags: shoes

-I’m getting ready to polish my black leather Tennis shoes and I would  like suggestion to keep it getting On my white soles.

Answer (score 5):

You could carefully cover the white soles with painter's masking tape (also called FROGTAPE™) and remove the tape after you finish.

The masking tape will prevent the polish from penetrating through. It can be removed without any chemicals as it holds by a liquid-tight adhesive bond.

[image: white soled shoe masked for treatment]